# Testing Static function

Tags: testing, phpunit

I am newbie to Testing. I am using PHPUnit Framework. I read mocking and stubbing about static functions but even those concepts are new to me. I want to unit test the following function

```
class Company implements ifOrm {
    public $id              = null;
    public $externalId      = null;
    public $name            = null;
    public $created         = null;
    public $modified            = null;
    public $state = null;
    private $arrService = array();

    public function __construct($externalId, $name, $state) {
        $this->externalId = $externalId;
        $this->name = $name;        
        $this->state = $state;      
    }

    public static function factoryFromObject($obj) {
        $c = new Company($obj->external_id, $obj->name, $obj->state);
        // Tag it
        $c->id          = $obj->id;
        $c->created     = $obj->created;
        $c->modified   = $obj->modified;

        return $c;
    }
}
```

What i have done so far is the following

```
 class CompanyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
private $Company;

public function testFactoryFromObject()
{
    $this->Company = new Company( 004 ,'CompanyName','State');

    $returnObject = $this->Company->factoryFromObject($this->Company);

    $expectedId = $this->Company->id;
    $expectedCreated = $this->Company->created;
    $expectedModified = $this->Company->modified; 

    $actualId = $this->returnObject->id;
    $actualCreated = $this->returnObject->created;
    $actualModified = $this->returnObject->modified;

    assertEquals($expectedId, $actualId);
    assertEquals($expectedCreated, $actualCreated);
    assertEquals($expectedModified, $actualModified);       

   }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: Company::$external_id
```

How can i test this function, any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to access a property `external_id` when in your object, you defined it as `externalId`.  That is what is causing your error.

Comment: @Schleis.... Thanks. :), but now it gives the error "CompanyTest::testFactoryFromObject
Undefined property: CompanyTest::$returnObject". I don't know what is wrong here?

Comment: You created a variable `$returnObject` and then you are trying to access a property of your testCase `$this->returnObject` which doesn't exist.